Markup file slug in .NET
I am using Markdig nuget package right now to read my markup files and convert them to HTML
 string content = File.ReadAllText(mdFilepath);

 string? result = Markdown.ToHtml(content, pipeline);

But now I have added following lines to start of each blog :
---
title: 'This is the title of the blog'
description: 'Dummy description'
pubDate: 'Feb 11 2023'
coverImage: './blogs/covers/blog1.png'
---

This is blog, lorem ipsum ......
More content....

Additionally these lines in --- tags are not being read by File.ReadAllText method.
How can I create/use some sort of slug or a convertor/reader that I should get above details in a different model.

To read that block (which internally is YAML).

Add YAML front matter support to Markdig's parser by calling UseYamlFrontMatter() when building the parser pipeline.

When you have the AST from MarkdownParser.Parse(markdownContent, markdownPipeline) you can find the first YamlFrontMatterBlock
if (ast.FirstOrDefault(blk => blk is YamlFrontMatterBlock) is YamlFrontMatterBlock yb) {
   // yb is the front matter
}


You'll need a YAML parser (I've used YamlDotNet previously):
var yanl = yb.Lines.ToString();
var information = yamlDeserialiser.Deserialize<MarkdownFrontMatter>(yaml);



Where MarkdownFrontMatter is a type with the set of properties to extract (using nullable string properties to avoid problems should a property not have a value).
NB using
var html = Markdown.ToHtml(content, pipeline);

is just a short cut for:
var mdAst = MarkdownParser.Parse(content, pipeline);
var html = mdAst.ToHtml(pipeline);


Thank you for your answer, it at least gave me some directions. But I am not getting anything in the first block, I have omitted is condition and just tried to access the first block, but I am getting null, var firstBlock = mdAst.FirstOrDefault(); I have added .UseYamlFrontMatter() in pipeline

@Wasim note the predicate in the call to FirstOrDefault.

"ParagraphBlock" Line: 0, {}

@Wasim More clearly in my code I do _not _call FirstOrDefault(); instead I call FirstOrDefault(blk => blk is YamlFrontMatterBlock) so this returns the first instance of a YamlFrontMatterBlock in the AST or null this is not necessarily the first object in the AST.

My bad, the code worked first time, my markup was missing block
